# Odoo 15, Want to Modify Access Right of the Employee in Attendance Module ,

Tags: user-interface, debugging, odoo-15, record-rules

I'm new to Odoo and  want to modify the access right of the employee so s(he) can not modify the status of attendance only Respective Manager can change the status .
,such as cannot change it from pending to approved but can see the status as "approved / pending"
User name is "User" Type Internal ,officer in employees, officer in attendance module, Department s "IT"

I have tried record rules , through google but not able to achieve desired output